# subdomain show files of domain htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to show files on my subdomain, these files are located on the main domain.

I want something like this

```
domain.com/some-folder/
subdomain.domain.com/some-folder/ (" folder doesn't really exist")

domain.com/some-file.html
subdomain.domain.com/some-file.html ("file doesn't really exist")

domain.com/some-folder/with-an-inside-file.html
subdomain.domain.com/some-folder/with-an-inside-file.html ("file and folder don't really exist")
```

I have seen a similar idee on apple.com

images.apple.com/uk/ will show up the same page as apple.com/uk/ and
images.apple/uk will redirect to apple.com/uk/ (notice there is no end-slash in the second example)

My current code so far (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

This code will redirect to domain.com/ but how can I just show up the content of 
domain.com/ without redirecting to domain.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mod-proxy**

If the files are on different servers, you'll have to use `mod-proxy`, which may or may not be installed. If it is installed, use the `P` flag in your existing rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [P]
```

---

**Reference**

[Using mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/proxy.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the subdomain to have the same document root? Much easier ;) For a variety of reasons, I currently have quite a number of such subdomain aliases, and I can tell you that they work great.

Comment: How can I achieve that?

Comment: When you set up the subdomain, you should be asked for the document root. It depends on your host, though, so you should ask them.

Comment: Oke thanks for your answer, but isn't there anyway to achieve it with htaccess?

Comment: Possibly, if you rewrite to where the actual files are rather than redirecting.